# Kali Linux - Fast TSC Calibration Failed When Trying To Install 1.0.9 on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, calibration

I'm trying to install Kali Linux 1.0.9 on VirtualBox, but upon selecting Install, I get a "Fast TSC Calibration Failed" error then the VM closes down automatically.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm trying to familiarize myself with Kali Linux to pursue a Network Security career/hobby, so I'm a complete beginner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*"TSC"* is the Time Stamp Counter, there's usually no problem when this error surfaces. It means that the first try to calibrate the TSC has failed, but calibration will succeed later-on after retry attempts as can be seen by checking /var/log/messages.log after boot.

Perhaps there are errors later on but you can't see them because the VM is closed?